# Conditioned Expectations given a sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am given that $\hat\theta=X_1$ and $T={X_1+X_2}$

towards application of the Rao-Blackwell theorem, I understand that $\tilde\theta=E[\hat\theta|T]$

The Rao-Blackwell part is more for context, it is the conditional expectation that I'm struggling with

Conceptually this is where I hit a snag. The lecture notes say that

$\tilde{\theta}=E(\hat{\theta}|T)=E(X_1|X_1+X_2)=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$

Conceptually, what does it mean for there to be an Expected Value of $X_i$ or $X_1$ GIVEN something like $X_1+X_2$, and by extension, why is it $= \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$

Similarly, what if I had a different sufficient statistic, say $\bar X$, what would $\tilde{\theta}=E(\hat{\theta}|T)$ be?

In general is there an explanation in words that might help me to understand this better?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the specific question:

$$E[X_1 \mid X_1 + X_2] + E[X_2 \mid X_1 + X_2] = E[X_1 + X_2 \mid X_1 + X_2] = X_1 + X_2.$$
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exchangeable (I suspect in your situation, they are i.i.d., which implies exchangeability), then the two terms on the left-hand side are equal,  so each must equal $\frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}$.

---

Regarding the "meaning" of the conditional expectation: $X_1$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are two random variables on the same probability space, so the conditional expectation $E[X_1 \mid X_1 + X_2]$ is defined just as you would define $E[X \mid Y]$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$. I would recommend reviewing where you first learned about conditional expectation, or asking a more specific question about what you are confused about, since "what is conditional expectation" is too broad a question to be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional expectation is the orthogonal projection of the preimage of the borel sets of two random variable onto each other. The amount of intersection in the preimage for the same borel sets is a measure of dependence. If the sigma algebra has the same open sets under conditioning the random variables are orthogonal